# Split long string by Array condition

Tags: javascript, split

I have a long string:

> JOHN GULLIBLE DOE CENTER FOR FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE TO DEPOSED NIGERIAN
> ROYALTY421 E DRACHMAN TUCSON AZ 85705-7598 USA

I have an array:

> ["FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE","CANADA","NIGERIAN","TUCSON AZ","US"]

I want to split the string above by the values in the array, if the value in the array not found(CANADA), just skip it

I want my output is:

> ["JOHN GULLIBLE DOE CENTER FOR ","FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE"," TO DEPOSED
> NIGERIAN ROYALTY421 E DRACHMAN ", "TUCSON AZ","85705-7598", "USA"]

This is my solution using Regex:

```
    const regexString = "(" + array.join("|") + ")";
    regExp = new RegExp(regexString);
```

I created a regex like this: (FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE|CANADA|NIGERIAN|TUCSON AZ|US)

Then I split the string by that regex:

```
string.split(regExp).filter(t => t !== "");
```

Everything works except for the last case "US", This is the output that I got:

> ["JOHN GULLIBLE DOE CENTER FOR ","FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE"," TO DEPOSED
> NIGERIAN ROYALTY421 E DRACHMAN ", "TUCSON AZ","85705-7598", "US", "A"]

Comment: `["FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE","CANADA","NIGERIAN","TUCSON AZ","USA?"]` can you add an A? to the US in your array?

Comment: @user2182349, Nope, that is the problem, the array was given, so I need to find a way to handle the whitespace around the words aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the word boundary `\b` before/after each piece:

```js
const string = "JOHN GULLIBLE DOE CENTER FOR FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE TO DEPOSED NIGERIAN ROYALTY421 E DRACHMAN TUCSON AZ 85705-7598 USA";
const array = ["FINANCIAL ASSISTANCE","CANADA","NIGERIAN","TUCSON AZ","US"];
const regexString = "(\\b)(" + array.join("|") + ")(\\b)";
regExp = new RegExp(regexString);
console.log(string.split(regExp).filter(t => t !== ""));
```